# Excel - Pivot Table Calculated Field Count of Dates Field Error

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that is counting the amount of records from two date data type columns. One column will have a value for the full size of the sample, while the other will either have a value or be blank. I have no issue of counting these columns when dropping them in the "Values" section of the pivot table, but when I try to create a calculated field that divides one column by the other, I receive an error value. Is this due to the data type for both the columns (date)? When I do `COUNT(column)/COUNT(column)` I receive 100%, which is incorrect. Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

**Here is an example of the data being divided:**

*Lead Created Date/Time* = `1/1/2017  1:09:00 AM`

*First Paying Date* = `1/20/2017`

**Here is the calculated field (CVR):**

`='First Paying Date'/'Lead Created Date/Time'`

**Here is the output:**

[image: excel calculated field error]

Comment: Why are you trying to divide two dates, don't you want to subtract them instead?  That would give you the time between the two dates.

Comment: I actually want to divide the count of the two dates to determine a conversion rate, however as I pointed out in my example in the body, `COUNT('First Paying Date')/COUNT('Lead Created Date/Time'` renders 100% for every row in my pivot table.

Comment: OK, I get it finally.  You're not dividing dates, you're trying to divide a count of the *number* of dates in each column.  Something is going on with your COUNT() function.  Test it.  Does it correctly count the values in each column alone?  It should count only numbers or dates and exclude blank and empty cells.

Comment: That COUNTA unfortunately does not render the correct division. Every record appears with 100%. [http://imgur.com/a/Pykq5](http://imgur.com/a/Pykq5)

Comment: I meant test it by counting the two columns *separately*.  The answer should be a number, not 100%. If your columns have only dates and blanks, you should get the number of dates.  Test it.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm not sure I follow. I think I understand you last suggestion creating a custom formula column with the formula of `=COUNTA('First Paying Date')`, which would be counting two columns separately, but the result of that column is the value of `1` for each row in the pivot table. Here is a screen grab [http://imgur.com/a/zJsnu](http://imgur.com/a/zJsnu). I'm surprised that such a simple objective of dividing the first column by the second column is so tedious for a pivot table.

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show any blank cells, but I assume there are some.  Here's the problem, I think. CountA() won't count *empty* cells, but it will count cells that have a formula, even if that formula returns blank ("").

Comment: If that's what is going on, try this formula: `1-COUNTBLANK(column)/COUNTBLANK(column)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately your formula renders an error (`=(1-COUNTBLANK( 'First Paying Date'))/COUNTBLANK( 'Lead Created Date/Time')`). I have also tried `IF('First Paying Date'="",0,1)/IF('Lead Created Date/Time'="",0,1)` to take into consideration the blank fields and had no success. I'm just going to run the formula on a sheet containing the pasted aggregated values. It is incredibly frustrating how ineffective excel's calculated formula functionality can be. Thank you for all of your help with this problem